# Forcing the browser to reload what's between a textarea tag

Tags: html, textarea

I've noticed that my browser only loads the textarea tag on my page once:

IE:

```
<textarea> Hello Hello Hello </textarea>
```

If I modify the textarea **in the browser** these browser side changes will remain even when I refresh the page.

If I modify it **in the html file** the browser will not reload the changes.

It's as if once the browser has loaded my page once, the value of that textarea is stored locally and retrieved locally each time. This is annoying because the value of my textarea is changed by the server from time to time.

Can I force the browser to use the contents of the textarea from the server on each refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Check if preventing caching in the IE helps.

Here's the meta tag add it to your html

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Let me know if that works.

Go through this link from Microsoft

[Prevent caching of files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)